# Program or library to read an Excel-based schedule hourly and read content out loud

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, programming

I have an Excel-based hourly schedule that I change and check throughout the day.
[image]

Is there some tool that would check every hour in the particular day and hour (see column and row) and if there is something there read it out loud to me? (And if blank, do some other action.)

If there's no such tool, I might program one, preferably in Python or VBA. Suppose I wanted to program such a tool in Python or VBA, what libraries could I use?

Answer (score 3):

It should be completely possible using python with the following libraries:

- datetime *built in library*
- [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/) *excel read library*
- [pyttsx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttsx) *text to speech library*

Comment: Any suggestions on what subjects to study so I can create this product? I'm new to development in general and only have some experience with AHK.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at one or more of the many free or paid for books/sites for learning python, Think Python http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/ might be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Windows Script Host (WSH) run on a timed loop, and open the Excel file, extract the data, and use the Speech API (SAPI) to read the text out loud.

You have two choices to extract the data:
* Create a hidden Excel instance, open the workbook, read the particular cell
* Connect to the Excel workbook via ActiveX Data Objects (ADODB) and issue an SQL statement against it

You might be able to do all of this in AHK, using [COM functions](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ComObjCreate.htm). I'm not familiar with AHK, but I presume it has some sort of timer built-in?

Links:

VBScript / WSH / Scripting Runtime

- [JScript and VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1et7k7c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), specifically the [VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [Script Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bstcxhf7%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), and [Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) sections.

ADODB

- [Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [How to use ADO to read and write data in Excel workbooks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278973)
- [VBScript ADO Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - because most of the ADO samples are in VB6/VBA
- [Connecting to an Excel workbook with ADO](http://www.fontstuff.com/ebooks/free/fsadoconnectexcel.pdf) - most useful reference I've found

[Excel developer reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ee861528.aspx)

[SAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125663(v=vs.85).aspx)